# Сравнить 2 массива и вывести несовпадающие значения

Tags: javascript, массивы

есть 2 массива типа:

```
let arr1 = [[1000046748,    130.06],  
[1000046749,    85.2],
[1000046750,    4.5]];
let arr2 = [[1000046748,    130.06],
[1000046750,    4.5],
[1000046751,    58.82]];
```

нужно отдельно получить разницу между первым и вторым и наоборот. Вложеность массивов большая, как сделать это оптимально?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let arr1 = [ [1000046748, 130.06], [1000046749, 85.2], [1000046750, 4.5] ];
let arr2 = [ [1000046748, 130.06], [1000046750, 4.5],  [1000046751, 58.82] ];

let lookup1 = arr1.reduce(function(result, item){ 
  result[item[0] + "_" + item[1]] = item;
  return result;
}, {});
let lookup2 = arr2.reduce(function(result, item){ 
  result[item[0] + "_" + item[1]] = item;
  return result;
}, {});

let diff12 = [];
for (let key in lookup1) {
  if (!lookup2[key])
    diff12.push(lookup1[key]);
}
let diff21 = [];
for (let key in lookup2) {
  if (!lookup1[key])
    diff21.push(lookup2[key]);
}

console.log(diff12);
console.log(diff21);
```

Доработать, если в любом из массивов возможны одинаковые элементы.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь